# VBA Access SQL - field within LIKE operator

Tags: sql, ms-access

Can I use a table column within a Like operator?  I've created an example,

TableA

```
Names                    Location 
Albert Smith Senior      Aberdeen  
John Lee                 London  
Michael Rogers Junior    Newcastle  
Mary Roberts             Edinburgh
```

TableB

```
Names  
Albert Smith  
John Lee  
Michael Rogers
```

I want to do a query such as:

```
SELECT TableA.Location 
into NewTable 
FROM TableA
WHERE TableA.Names Like '*[TableB.Names]*';
```

In this case, there would be no match for Mary Roberts, Edinburgh but the first three locations would be returned.

Is it possible to put a column into a like statement?
If not does anyone have any ideas how I could do this?

Hope you can help

PS I can't use an actual asterisk since this is removed and the text italicised, also I have read about using % instead but this has not worked for me.

Comment: @TBone...Is there an "in" statement in VBA SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can join the two tables and use `LIKE` within the `JOIN` clause:

```
SELECT TableA.Location
into NewTable 
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.Names LIKE TableB.Names & '*';
```

Honestly, I had no idea that you can do this in Access before I tried it just now :-)

Comment: If you want to use `%` as the wildcard character, change `LIKE` to `ALIKE` e.g. `...TableA.Names ALIKE TableB.Names & '%';`