# UPDATE statement with multiple WHERE conditions

Tags: sql, t-sql, ms-access

I'm trying to run an `UPDATE` query in Access with different `WHERE` conditions:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET [Ticker] = "TXSFI" WHERE [Acct Numb] like "*03",
SET [Ticker] = "TESEI" WHERE [Acct Numb] like "*04";
```

Why do I get an error?

Comment: Use `'` instead of `"` for SQL string literals

Comment: You can't have 2 `where` clauses in 1 query.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but when I am trying to execute this, it is showing error as missing operator.

Comment: @juergend: Is there any way that we can update single coloum with more than 2 where statement?

Answer (score 22):

You can do this with two update statement:

```
UPDATE Table1
    SET Table1.[Ticker] = 'TXSFI' WHERE Table1.[Acct Numb] like '*03';

Update Table1
    SET Table1.[Ticker] = 'TESEI' WHERE Table1.[Acct Numb] like '*04';
```

Or, you can combine these using conditional updates (non-Access version):

```
update table1
   SET Table1.[Ticker] = (case when  Table1.[Acct Numb] like '%03' then 'TXSFI'
                               when Table1.[Acct Numb] like '%04' then 'TESEI'
                          end)
   where Table1.[Acct Numb] like '%03' or Table1.[Acct Numb] like '%04'
```

By the way, I am guessing that you are using Access.  The standard wildcard in SQL would be `like '%03'` but Access uses a `'*'` instead of `'%'`.  It is a good idea to tag your question with the database you are using.

Having said that, you can't use `case` in Access:

```
update table1
   SET Table1.[Ticker] = iif(Table1.[Acct Numb] like '*03', 'TXSFI', 'TESEI')
   where Table1.[Acct Numb] like '*03' or Table1.[Acct Numb] like '*04'
```

Comment: Thanks. 1st one is working fine for me. Sorry for incomplete question. Yes, I am using Access for my query. Thanks again. Really Appreciated.

Comment: UPDATE Table1 SET Table1.[Ticker_Symbol_Id] = 'DUMMY' WHERE Table1.[Acct Numb] not like ( '*01'. '*03'. '*04'. '*07'. '*08'. '*09'); Can't we use not like statement in Update query?

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to do this with **one single query** (without nesting `IIF`s), no matter how many different `WHERE` clauses you have.

This is similar to what I described in [my answer here (second part)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17369592/6884):

1. Create a temporary table which looks like this:

   ```
   Acct Numb      NewTicker
   -------------------------
   *03            TXSFI
   *04            TESEI
   ```

   You can enter as many new rows as you want, each one with a "filter value" for the account number and a new `Ticker` value.
2. Update all values in `Table1` with this single query:

   ```
   UPDATE Table1
   INNER JOIN tmp ON Table1.[Acct Numb] LIKE tmp.[Acct Numb]
   SET Table1.Ticker = tmp.NewTicker;
   ```

   Yes, the `JOIN` part looks strange at first glance, but [it's actually possible to join with `LIKE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10218329/6884).
3. You can delete the temporary table again when you're finished.