# UPDATE multiple WHERE SQL not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run a query to update the `DATA` table where the `MAXNVQ` is different it will update a different value into the Burnham Grade column.

This is my code so far:-

```
UPDATE Data  
SET Data.BurnhamGrade = (CASE WHEN Data.[MAXNVQ] > 3 THEN 'Grade II/III' 
                              WHEN Data.[MAXNVQ] = 3 THEN 'Grade IV' 
                              WHEN Data.[MAXNVQ] < 3 THEN 'Grade IV' END)
WHERE (MAXNVQ > 3) OR
       (MAXNVQ = 3) OR
         (MAXNVQ < 3)
```

I get an error saying SQL Execution Error:

> String or binary data would be truncated the statement has been
>   terminated.

Like I have been a mistake in the SQL

Comment: Not that this will fix anything, but you can get rid of your `where` clause altogether.  It doesn't accomplish anything.

Comment: Umm... your condition is always true (unless `MAXNVQ` is nullable). What are you trying to do?

Comment: I get an error saying SQL Execution Error. String or binary data would be truncated the statement has been terminated.  Like I have been a mistake in the SQL

Comment: What is the datatype for data.burnhamgrade?

Comment: That's just saying the `BurnhamGrade` column isn't large enough for the data you're trying to save there. Perhaps it's just `varchar(8)` or something?

Comment: It means the column `BurnhamGrade` has less character length than you are trying to assign it to.

Comment: I researched my question first got help from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17406352/update-statement-with-multiple-where-conditions and then tried it myself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this should be a comment, but the comments seem to be about other topics.  Your query (or the equivalent) is:

```
UPDATE Data  
    SET Data.BurnhamGrade = (CASE WHEN Data.[MAXNVQ] > 3 THEN 'Grade II/III' 
                                  WHEN Data.[MAXNVQ] = 3 THEN 'Grade IV' 
                                  WHEN Data.[MAXNVQ] < 3 THEN 'Grade IV' END)
    WHERE MAXNVQ IS NOT NULL;
```

If you are getting a data truncation error, it would be because the strings assigned to `Data.BurnhamGrade` are too long for the column.   So, check the length of the column.

A common reason for this is when the length is left off the variable.  So, if your table is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE data (
    . . .
    BurnhamData varchar,
    . . .
);
```

This assigns a default length to the column, which depends on context and is often "1".  There is no error, just a column that is shorter than you intend.  Instead:

```
CREATE TABLE data (
    . . .
    BurnhamData varchar(255),
    . . .
);
```

Or, if this mapping is *always* true, store the values in a reference table and use a `JOIN`, Or, use a computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE data
    ADD BurnhamGrade AS (CASE WHEN Data.[MAXNVQ] > 3 THEN 'Grade II/III' 
                              WHEN Data.[MAXNVQ] = 3 THEN 'Grade IV' 
                              WHEN Data.[MAXNVQ] < 3 THEN 'Grade IV' 
                         END)
```

With this approach, you don't have to worry about keeping the value up-to-date.  It will be correct whenever you query the table and use the column.

Comment: **Comment:**  I clearly suggest to use `nvarchar(x)` nowadays, instead of `varchar(x)`. `nvarchar` is Unicode, which means 2 bytes per character, but you can store basically all characters from all languages in the world (even chinese, etc.) without any headaches. `varchar` is 8-bit and you will get headaches if you want to insert letters like äöüè etc. Times have changed. The world is round, cpus are fast, and memory is cheap.

Comment: @SQLPolice Not all of unicode can be stored in 2-byte-per-codepoint, UTF-16 leads to all sorts of bugs.

Comment: @o11c That's right, but beyond others, all latin diacritics are provided, you have no problems with sorting & comparing, and you have never problems with displaying these characters in other countries. Usage of 8-bit-characters is essentially an *old habit to kick*. Except if you have good technical reasons. And can you please provide an example for bugs relating out of Unicode usage?

Comment: @SQLPolice try to paste the contents of [this gist](https://gist.github.com/o11c/9f5c51c06654a44665d2), I will in another comment. It works in most utf-8-based applications, but fails (or exhibits bugs) on many utf-16-based applications.

Comment: @SQLPolice begin quote:      ,     ""    … end quote

Comment: @o11c Nice ;) -- Pasted it via SSMS into a database: **Works.** However, there is a display problem in the Flexgrid component of the client UI. However, pasted it into an internationally used  C# application, which was translated to Farsi: **Works.** Pasting in Excel works, also. But Notepad++ has a problem. ==> Well, this is a constructed example, but nice. Of course, an application should be able to handle it!

Comment: @o11c But on one side, this is an artificially constructed example; on the other side, it still provides no reason for preferring `varchar` over `nvarchar`. In fact, `nvarchar` **can** store even this weird string, and a modern user interface should be able to handle it.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the comments it's likely that the column you are updating (`BurnhamGrade`) is not big enough to hold the data that you are inserting in to it.

E.g. if your column definition is: `BurnhamGrade VARCHAR(10)` you wouldn't be able to insert `'Grade II/III'` as it's 12 characters long.

This recreates the error:

```
CREATE TABLE #data
    (
      MAXNVQ INT ,
      BurnhamGrade VARCHAR(10)
    )

INSERT  INTO #data
        ( [MAXNVQ], BurnhamGrade )
VALUES  ( 1, '' ),
        ( 3, '' ),
        ( 4, '' )

UPDATE  #data
SET     #data.BurnhamGrade = ( CASE WHEN MAXNVQ > 3 THEN 'Grade II/III'
                                    WHEN MAXNVQ = 3 THEN 'Grade IV'
                                    WHEN MAXNVQ < 3 THEN 'Grade IV'
                               END )
-- NOTE THE WHERE CLAUSE ISN'T REQUIRED UNLESS HANDLING NULLS

SELECT  *
FROM    #data

DROP TABLE #data
```

**Produces:**

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 11
>   String or binary data would be truncated.

Modifying the column specification to: `BurnhamGrade VARCHAR(12)` allows it to work.

After the change, it produces:

```
MAXNVQ  BurnhamGrade
1       Grade IV
3       Grade IV
4       Grade II/III
```

So altering the column definition to a larger value should fix the issue.

One final thing, you can merge 2 of your cases so:

```
WHEN MAXNVQ = 3 THEN 'Grade IV'
WHEN MAXNVQ < 3 THEN 'Grade IV'
```

Can use `<= 3` as they set the same value, like so:

```
WHEN MAXNVQ <= 3 THEN 'Grade IV'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the data you are trying to put in the field is bigger than the size allowed for the field.  There is nothing wrong with your SQl at all (except as @sstan pointed out in the comments, the where clasue is not needed).

The problem is what to do about it. You have two choices and the decision to change things is a business decsion not a programming decision.

You can increase the size of the field to accomodate all the possible values.
 or 
You can change the possible values so that they fit into the size of the field as currently defined.

Mu guess would be they would prefer the first solution, but that will require full regression testing of your aplication and any imports or exports or reports that use the column. However sometimes, the schema is not changeable especially if you are putting data into a database designed for a third-party application. In that case you have no choice but to abbreviate the value so that it fits into the table.