# SQL insert new values into new column from the beginning of table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I added a new column named `roomNumber` to my `hotel` table which already has some values. But when I try inserting new values into `hotel` the values would get inserted from where the current data finished rather than at the beginning.

my query

```
INSERT INTO hotel
(roomNumber) 
VALUES
    (20),
    (60),
    (100),
    (20),
    (20),
    (150),
    (50),
    (50),
    (30),
    (50);
```

The values started inserting from where id = 10 , rather I want it to insert where id = 1 (at the beginning)
[image]

Comment: The `INSERT` statement does not match the image.

Comment: "...The values started inserting from where id = 10 , rather I want it to insert where id = 1 (at the beginning)..." -- Why do you care about the specific values of the ID column? It doesn't really matter which IDs are being used. The only important consideration is that the primary key needs to be UNIQUE; that's all. Moreover, tables do not have inherent row ordering; in other words theres' no beginning or end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `INSERT` data you will create new rows for the new data. If you want to change existing rows you need to `UPDATE` those rows.

So, to update your three existing rows you need three `UPDATE` queries<sup>*</sup>:

```
UPDATE hotel set roomNumber = 20 where id=8
UPDATE hotel set roomNumber = 60 where id=9
UPDATE hotel set roomNumber = 100 where id=10
```

I've assumed your primary key column is called `id` - you may have a different name for it.

Then to insert your remaining data you can run an `INSERT` query:

```
INSERT hotel (name, roomNumber) 
  values 
    ('Excelsior',20),
    ('Manor Park Hotel', 20) 
    etc.
```

I've invented some hotel names here since it seems to make little sense to insert a room count with no hotel name.

Note that 'beginning of the table' has no real meaning in SQL. The order of rows is not guaranteed unless you specify an `ORDER BY` clause, but that's not relevant here. To update a specific row you need to specify a `WHERE` clause that identifies that row. The Primary Key is a common way to do that.

<sup>*</sup> You could do the three updates with a single `UPDATE` query if you use a suitable `WHERE` clause, but that seems needlessly complicated for three rows.

Answer (score 0):

When using SQL `insert` you are inserting new rows into a table. You want to update the existing rows, then run an insert for the rest of the new data.

[UPDATE statement with multiple WHERE conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17406352/update-statement-with-multiple-where-conditions)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to insert the data from ID 1?

You need to use `UPDATE`, not `INSERT`. As the rows already exist.